# Method 'Open' of object'_Recordset' failed in SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm looking to create an SQL query that will return the Case Manager, total number of activity & count of description that begins with 'Outgoing Calls'.

At the moment, I run this and get an error message saying Method 'Open' of object'_Recordset' failed. I'm sure it's because of 'Outgoing Calls' because it works fine when I remove it.

Can anyone see why this is failing, or know any alternative way of counting the number of descriptions that begin with Outgoing Calls? Bear in mind that Case method does not work on VBA.

```
SELECT m.CaseManager, 
SUM(m.Lead) AS 'Total Leads', 
COUNT(a.Description) AS 'Total Activity', 
COUNT(IF a.Description LIKE 'Outgoing Calls%' THEN 1 ENDIF) AS 'Outbound Calls' 
FROM AccountTable m INNER JOIN ActivityTable a 
ON m.AccountNumber=a.AccountNumber 
GROUP BY m.CaseManager;
```

Comment: Try executing the query directly in Access instead of from VBA code: you might get a more meaningful error message. The recordset is failing to open because of a syntax error in the SQL; the SQL editor should give better clues about what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** The statement if `IIF`, not `IF`
**(2)** The IIF-statement needs an `ELSE`-branch

cannot test it for the moment, but statement should look like

```
SUM(IIF(a.Description LIKE 'Outgoing Calls*', 1, 0)) AS 'Outbound Calls'
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Comment: Thanks - I'm unfortunately seeing the same error message as above when I add this.

Comment: @DannyO'Sullivan try `IIF(a.Description LIKE 'Outgoing Calls%',1,0)`. `IIF` is a function that takes arguments, not a statement. You're mixing up `IIF` function and `SELECT CASE` statements; `CASE WHEN a.Description LIKE 'Outgoing Calls%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` should also work (note: I don't know Access-SQL).

Comment: Sorry, mixed  things up. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks guys. Oddly enough, the query above returns the total number of activities rather than just the Outgoing calls. So essentially the IIF statement returns the same as COUNT(a.Description). (And I can confirm that it's not supposed to be the same count.

Comment: You need to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. COUNT counts the number of hits of a query. And the wildcard in Access-SQL is `*`, not '%'. Updated my answer one more time and hope it is correct now

Comment: Yes this answer is correct. Thanks for your help.